# Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process but not all the time

Tags: c#

Its quite weird,i have a console application that reads media file and extract some data from media file using third party dll (MediaInfo.dll)

and then i upload that file to some other location from the source then finally i delete that file in the souce once everything is don.

Below is my code for deletion.

```
                    GC.Collect();
                    FileInfo[] fiListImages = (new DirectoryInfo(mfsData.Images)).GetFiles(String.Format("*{0}*", sp.Story.Slug));
                    foreach (FileInfo fi in fiListImages)
                    {

                        bool ImageFolder = fi.Directory.Name.Contains("Images");
                        if (ImageFolder)
                        {

                            File.Delete(fi.FullName);

                        }
                    }

                    FileInfo[] fiListMedia = (new DirectoryInfo(mfsData.EncodedMedia)).GetFiles(String.Format("*{0}*", sp.Story.Slug), SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    foreach (FileInfo fi in fiListMedia)
                    {



                        if (sp.Profile.Name == "Comedy" && fi.FullName.Contains(@"\Comedy"))
                        {
                            File.Delete(fi.FullName);
                        }
                        else if (sp.Profile.Name == "Actuib" && ((fi.FullName.Contains(@"\Action") || (fi.FullName.Contains(@"\Syndicated")))))
                        {
                            File.Delete(fi.FullName);
                        }


                    }
```

I just want to call the garbage collector before start deletion ( i thought this will help me to remove all the locks but am wrong).

The code is working really good some times and sometimes it throws this exception "Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

I can suspect another place when i load the media file to the third party library like below

```
                videoInterrogator.LoadFile(filename);
                logger.Info("video interrogar extract the video files");
                message.AppendFormat(messageFormat, "FileSize", videoInterrogator.GetFileSize(), Environment.NewLine);
                message.AppendFormat(messageFormat, "MaxBitRate", videoInterrogator.maxBitRate(), Environment.NewLine);
                logger.Info("Video Extract done");
```

after get in to this piece of code when i try to delete that file manually i get the same error message and am not sure how to close the connection forcefully to release the file.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: proper formatting and indentation of the code much appreciated

Comment: I don't know what in the world your `videoInterrogator` is. But if it it is a third party application/library and is uploading files to network then it must have some event which should be raised when it finishes its task.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot, VideoInterrogator is my wrapper class calling the 3rd party dll (media info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More information about `videoInterrogator` would definitely be useful. Try checking its documentation. If it implements `IDisposable` try calling `Dispose()` on the object once you're done. If it's a COM object call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will add the VideoInterrogator code also can you please suggest me,why its working sometimes and why its not someother times ?

Comment: @Usher The times when it's not working, there's a lock on the file that's preventing it from deletion, probably from the third party library. If it's not a managed library, calling garbage collector is not enough to release it. Is [this](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) the library you are using?

Comment: Exactly am using the same library you mentioned and written in C++.